# How format mac address inside json array

Tags: sed, formatting, mac-address

Need help in getting below the mac address inside the json file to re-reformatted using sed
cat 251.json

```
 cat /tmp/251.json


   [
  "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c",
  "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3d",
  "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3e",
  "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3f",
  "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
  "b8:83:03:81:4b:21",
  "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c",
  "b8:83:03:84:d5:1d"
]
```

The expected format is

```
 [
  "08f1.ea6d.033c",
  "08f1.ea6d.033d",
  "08f1.ea6d.033e",
  "08f1.ea6d.033f",
  "b883.0381.4b20",
  "b883.0381.4b21",
  "b883.0384.d51c",
  "b883.0384.d51d"
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -E 's/:(.{2}):(.{2}):(.{2}):(.{2}):/\1.\2\3.\4/g' /tmp/251.json
```

In this way, you get the output to stdout. If you want to modify the file, add the `-i` option. You can check the result [here](https://ideone.com/Xdi8Ep).

Comment: @BharatGupta why don't you take a look at the "[What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers?)" section? I saw that you never accepted an answer and that you thank in comments, maybe it could be useful for you and the community